# How do I set up monthly contribitions in Paypal

Tags: paypal

I am a novice when it comes to coding buttons in Paypal. We are a non profit ORG and we currently have the "donate now" button for a 1 time contribution. I want to change this to allow for a monthly (reoccurring) contribution amount. What button/API do I use and can you share some sample code?

I am also not sure how this process would work. Does the person that wants to contribute on a monthly basis (ex: $10/month) need to have their own paypal account? Or, does our paypal business account store the persons credit card info and would know to bill the person monthly? Our current donate button doesn't require the person to have a paypay account. They just enter their credict card info at the time of the 1 time donation. But it does allow them to log on to paypal if they do have an account. Any info would be helpful....

Answer (score 0):

Charlie,

I recommend you to use **PayPal standard subscription** button.

For sample code, [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_subscribe/#basic-subscribe-button)

By default, the buyers either have a PayPal account or have to create a PayPal account to buy your subscription plan.

But you could contact & request to [PayPal Customer support team](http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_contact-general) to enable [**Enhanced Recurring Payments**](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/us-erp-full) for your PayPal business account.

With ERP, the buyers could buy a subscription either using PayPal account or direct credit card without PayPal account.